# Error occurred with installation of Invantive Data Hub on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

When trying to install Invantive Data Hub on a Windows 2016 server I get the following error:

```
An error occurred trying to download 'https://download.invantive.com/environments/L528650790/stable/clickonce/invantive-data-hub-2016R1/install.application'.

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSDDB4B.tmp\install.log' for more information.
```

Logfile:

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 3 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 10.0.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read integer value 394802
Setting value '394802 {int}' for property 'DotNet45Full_Release'
Reading value 'v4' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\OS Integration'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNet45Full_OSIntegrated'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_OSIntegrated] = 1 {int}
Property: [DotNet45Full_Release] = 394802 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_Release' and value '379893': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_Release' and value '379893': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697208'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'https://download.invantive.com/environments/L528650790/stable/clickonce/invantive-data-hub-2016R1/install.application'.
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basis of this error is coming from a Microsoft ClickOnce-based installer.

There are two possibilities:

- The file is either on a CDN which is not yet replicated/filled correctly.
- You are running on a server with too tight security.

For option 1: try again in 30 minutes.

For option 2: download the file `install.application` from the URL listed in the error directly using Internet Explorer and run it.